# Mongoose save multiple sub-documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a huge collection (millions) called User.

```
User {
   userid: ObjectId,
   person: {ref: 'person', type: ObjectId},
   details: {ref: 'details', type: ObjectId},
   address: {ref: 'address', type: ObjectId},
   other: {ref: 'other', type: ObjectId}
}
```

It has a reference to other collections (Person, Details, Address, Other).

Now I have an API to create new users, so I send a User object that contains all the data needed :

```
user = {
    person: {...},
    details: {...},
    address: {...},
    other: {...}
}
```

I don't want duplicates in my collections, so right now I'm doing :

```
let options = {upsert: true, new: true};
let person = await Person.findOneAndUpdate({ personId: user.person.id }, user.person, options);
let details = await Details.findOneAndUpdate({ detailsId: user.details.id }, user.details, options);
let address = await Address.findOneAndUpdate({ addressId: user.address.id }, user.address, options);
let other = await Other.findOneAndUpdate({ otherId: user.other.id }, user.other, options);
```

Then I set the ids :

```
user.person = person._id;
user.details = details._id;
user.address = address._id;
user.other = other._id;
```

Then I save the user :

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, user, options)
```

It seems like a lot of operations, and since the User is pretty big and I have millions of data, saving 1 user takes about 1second which is pretty slow.

How could I do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wait findOneAndUpdate by findOneAndUpdate, you should start all and wait with Promise.All:

```
const allPromise = Array(4);
const options = {upsert: true, new: true};
allPromise[0] = Person.findOneAndUpdate({ personId: user.person.id }, user.person, options);
allPromise[1] = Details.findOneAndUpdate({ detailsId: user.details.id }, user.details, options);
allPromise[2] = Address.findOneAndUpdate({ addressId: user.address.id }, user.address, options);
allPromise[3] = Other.findOneAndUpdate({ otherId: user.other.id }, user.other, options);
const [person,details,address,other] = await Promise.all(allPromise);
```

Comment: I had other places where I could do this, and I got significant speed increase, I take this as an answer ! Thanks for reminding me of Promise.all :p